# Create new Dictionary with group and count based on existing Dictionary with tuple

Tags: c#

I have the current Dictionary testdict:

```
Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, string, string>> testdict
```

Which is basically a `Dictionary<autoID, Tuple<ignore, "shortcode", "product_name">>`

Example:

```
testdict.Add(1, new Tuple<int, string, string>(1, "555", "Light Blue"));
testdict.Add(2, new Tuple<int, string, string>(2, "122", "Majenta Red"));
testdict.Add(3, new Tuple<int, string, string>(2, "133", "Dark Yellow"));
testdict.Add(4, new Tuple<int, string, string>(1, "555", "Light Blue"));
testdict.Add(5, new Tuple<int, string, string>(1, "555", "Light Blue"));
testdict.Add(6, new Tuple<int, string, string>(2, "133", "Dark Yellow"));
testdict.Add(7, new Tuple<int, string, string>(2, "766", "Purple"));
```

I need a new container that has this format:

```
autoid, "shortcode" group, "product_name" group, "count"
```

shortcode and product name always match, so they can be both grouped or group one and select any occurence of the second (first for example).
The int key can be ignored (it's just to create an order).
The int inside the tuple is also to be ignored.

An example of the new container I need would be:

```
Dictionary<int, Tuple<string, string, int>> newdict
newdict.Add(AutoID_Order, new Tuple<string, string, int>("shortcode", "product_name", count)); (structure)
newdict.Add(1, new Tuple<string, string, int>("555", "Light Blue", 3));
newdict.Add(2, new Tuple<string, string, int>("133", "Dark Yellow", 2));
newdict.Add(3, new Tuple<string, string, int>("122", "Majenta Red", 1));
newdict.Add(4, new Tuple<string, string, int>("766", "Purple", 1));
```

How can I accomplish this? Linq is acceptable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: We are not here to do your job for you. Show us your efforts (that you've tried at least something).

Comment: Found two questions in SO about grouping and counting with dicts, but none similar to this one. Always resulted in error converting one format to the other. I really appreciate the help from the two users who answered, and perhaps this will help other users in the future. Sorry for not posting the results from my attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int count=0;        
var z = testdict
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.Value.Item2, x.Value.Item3 })
        .ToDictionary(x => ++count, 
                      x => new Tuple<string, string, int>
                           (
                            x.Key.Item2, x.Key.Item3, x.Count()
                            ));
```

Comment: Thanks. Works fine. Only missing the orderby count, but I can do that in the view.

Comment: An .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()) bellow the groupby also solves it.

Comment: That will be `IGrouped` items. How in the world is that equivalent to  `Dictionary<int, Tuple<string, string, int>> newdict`. Wtever you do , at the end you have to use .ToDictionary` and `count` is just a variable here to index your results. There are probably better ways than using `count` variable to index but i don't know rit now.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your comment. The count I needed ordering is the x.Count() and not the count var. Don't needed it to be a proper ordered container, but since they are sent to the view in the same order they are inserted to the dict, it's enough. The way you wrote it works wonderfully.

Answer (score 1):

Use GroupBy and then use ToDictionary

```
testdict
  .GroupBy(x => new { x.Value.Item2, x.Value.Item3 })
  .Select((x, i) => new {
    i,
    ShortCode = x.Key.Item2,
    ProductName = x.Key.Item3,
    Count = x.Count(),
  })
  .ToDictionary(x => x.i, x => new Tuple<string, string, int>(x.ShortCode, x.ProductName, x.Count));
```

Comment: Instead of that First, why don't you GroupBy by the two properties? Then just use Key.Item1 and Key.Item2

Comment: Can't quite figure this: error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary>'

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, thanks... updated answer accordingly