# How to use identity aspnetusers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I asked a question earlier but I don't think I asked it correctly.

in my asp.net mvc application I am using aspnetusers for my login and registration.

If I have another model for Employees containing their information, How do I connect these two models so when a user logs in, it grabs their information from the employee table to be used. I created the Employees Model with sql server and used ado.net entity data model to use it in visual studio.

Employee Model:

```
 public partial class Employee
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    public int ShiftID { get; set; }
    public int AreaID { get; set; }
    public int DisciplineID { get; set; }
    public int SiteID { get; set; }
    public int ALCategory { get; set; }
    public int HoursTaken { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AwardedLeave { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TotalHoursThisYear { get; set; }
    public int HoursCarriedForward { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> EntitlementRemainingThisYear { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public int SickLeaveTaken { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SickLeaveEntitlement { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SickLeaveEntitlementRemaining { get; set; }
    public int StudyLeaveEntitlement { get; set; }
    public int StudyLeaveTaken { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> StudyLeaveRemaining { get; set; }
    public int ExamLeaveTaken { get; set; }
    public int ForceMajeure { get; set; }
    public int BereavementLeaveTaken { get; set; }
    public int MaternityLeaveTaken { get; set; }
    public int ParentalLeaveTaken { get; set; }
    public int AdoptionLeaveTaken { get; set; }
    public string ManagerEmail { get; set; }
    public string AreaManagerEmail { get; set; }

    public virtual Area Area { get; set; }
    public virtual Discipline Discipline { get; set; }
    public virtual Shift Shift { get; set; }
    public virtual Site Site { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee2 { get; set; }
}
```

And the log-in model:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

So can I connect these two? 
Does it matter that I use database first model?
Could I use a Foreign  Key to connect by email?

I want to use it for example to filter a table of employees to only show the employees who have the same siteID for the user logged in.

So when a user logs in, I want them to only see employees with the same site as themselves on the employee HTML table.

Comment: Sample dataset and desired result please.

Comment: @Sumitraj I've edited the question! Do you need more?

Comment: html is not needed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54277285/create-new-dictionary-with-group-and-count-based-on-existing-dictionary-with-tup/54277433#54277433 Check this and just provide a sample dataset. It will be much easier to understand.

Comment: How do you want me to present the dataset? I can show you teamviewer if you'd like!

Answer (score 0):

After successful login, you will get Id of AspNetUser. Take foreign key reference of column Id from AspNetUser table in your Employee table. By doing this, you can achieve expected result. Simply one more thing you need to add in your Employee model as mentioned below:

```
public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

Comment: So if my foreign key reference is Email. How do I add a foreign key to these two models?

Comment: You could add an EmailAddress also as foreign key but it should be unique key in your LoginViewModel [i.e. AspNetUser table]. As I said, Id [primary key] column of table AspNetUsers should be foreign key reference in table Employee and then add line of code in above mentioned comment to Employee model.